# How should I format json for a google bubble chart. I am not finding any specific documentation per the bubble chart

Tags: php, json, ajax, google-visualization

I want to pull data from a json file into google bubble chart. I am using the PHP and ajax example on a node js server. The question is how should the json code look ? I have not found specific examples. Thanks in andvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all google charts must be drawn using a google data table.

the general json format for a google data table can be found here...
[Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

which consists of two arrays, `cols` and `rows`

```
{
  cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'NEW A', type: 'string'},
         {id: 'B', label: 'B-label', type: 'number'},
         {id: 'C', label: 'C-label', type: 'date'}
  ],
  rows: [{c:[{v: 'a'},
             {v: 1.0, f: 'One'},
             {v: new Date(2008, 1, 28, 0, 31, 26), f: '2/28/08 12:31 AM'}
        ]},
         {c:[{v: 'b'},
             {v: 2.0, f: 'Two'},
             {v: new Date(2008, 2, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '3/30/08 12:31 AM'}
        ]},
         {c:[{v: 'c'},
             {v: 3.0, f: 'Three'},
             {v: new Date(2008, 3, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '4/30/08 12:31 AM'}
        ]}
  ],
  p: {foo: 'hello', bar: 'world!'}
}
```

in `rows`, each column may have a value (`v:`) and a formatted value (`f:`)

---

each chart has a specific [Data Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#data-format),
which describes the column types the chart expects.

for Bubble...

> Column 0 - string - ID (name) of the bubble
>   Column 1 - number - X coordinate
>   Column 2 - number - Y coordinate
>   Column 3 (optional) - string or number - Color; A value that is mapped to an actual color on a gradient scale using the `colorAxis` option
>   Column 4 (optional) - number - Size; values in this column are mapped to actual pixel values using the `sizeAxis` option

Comment: Ok , Thank you . I understand. I will put it all together. I just needed a starting point